# How to get path from actions from scheduled tasks using ComObject

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract information about the active scheduled tasks on a Windows 2003 Server, using PowerShell.

I found a useful script online for connecting to the scheduled tasks via a more up to date version of Windows:

```
$sch = New-Object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
$sch.Connect("10.22.8.54")
$tasks = $sch.GetFolder("\").GetTasks(0)
```

I look at the members of $tasks and there is a Definition property:

```
Definition            Property   ITaskDefinition Definition () {get}
```

I assign that to another variable and look at the members on that and see that there is an Actions property:

```
Actions          Property   IActionCollection Actions () {get} {set}
```

I assign that to another variable and see that there is a Path property:

```
Path             Property   string Path () {get} {set}
```

The actual line of code:

```
$tasks | %{if ($_.Enabled) {$z=$_.Definition;$y=$z.actions;$y.Path}}
```

This produces nothing.  How do I get the path?

I'm very new to powershell, so don't get too technical with me.

This works and shows the path (along with other info):

```
$tasks | %{if ($_.Enabled) {$z=$_.Definition;$z.actions}}
```

But how do I get just the path?

Comment: maybe `$z.actions.Path`?

Comment: yep - tried that - makes no difference

Comment: Does this not work? `$tasks | Where-Object{$_.Enabled} | Select-Object Path`?

Comment: Not sure what that is doing, but it seems to be extracting just the filename (without extension and without path)

Comment: Definitions for me contains `RegistrationInfo`,`Triggers`,`Settings`,`Data`,`Principal`,`Actions`,`XmlText`.... there is no path property there. You would be getting null trying to access a non existent property

Comment: Then why do I see a path property when I use get-member

Comment: Does this give you anything `$tasks | Where-Object{$_.Enabled} | ForEach-Object{([xml]$_.xml).Task.Actions.Exec.Command}`

Comment: Excellent - that did the trick - different approach, but it works - thank you

Comment: I think I might be confusing you with your code. The path property is the location in the Scedule task tree where the task is located. Your code looks like you think its in Definitions.

Comment: No definitely in Definitions.Actions.Path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is located inside the xml data of the scheduled task. Extracting the element from there would be a structured approach to get what you need.

```powershell
$tasks | Where-Object{$_.Enabled} | 
    ForEach-Object{
        ([xml]$_.xml).Task.Actions.Exec.Command
    }
```

We use a `Where-Object` clause to only look at enabled tasks. Then we cast the `xml` property as `[xml]`. Now we can access the command from within the actions section.

The results you get might be dependent on the OS you are querying. It might explain the difference in the results we were both getting.

You could easily get this in a calculated property if you needed to.

Comment: would still like to know why my approach doesn't work, but this has got round the problem anyway

Comment: Added a comment that might explain it. @Graham you don't mention what OS you were talking to. I was using 2008 R2 for my testing.